# Prevent Windows drives from mounting at startup

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I hope you are all doing well!

I have a simple problem, but also this is an issue that I cannot seem to find any resolution to no matter where I search online.
I have a computer with several OS's installed onto it including Mac OS, Ubuntu, and 2 Windows Installations. Each install is on a different HDD. I work from home and I have my main Windows install and I have a separate windows install for work.

What I am wanting to do is prevent Windows from mounting any other internal drives when windows is starting up so that when you go to "This PC" it will only show the current booted OS and not any other internal HDD's that are plugged in.
I have noticed windows will only show other windows formatted drives, for example, it will not show my Ubuntu drive nor my Mac Sierra Drive. I want this same result for my other Windows installation.

Any help to this issue would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much for your time and I hope you have an amazing rest of your day.

Comment: You could mark the other drive as "Offline" under Disk Management if all you want is simply "hide" it from being shown on "This PC".

Comment: turn off automount? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753703(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I tried turning off automount like you suggested but when I try it CMD doesnt recognize the command. I have windows 10 installed and it appears like this command no longer is valid in the latest windows version.

Comment: Nevermind, turning off automount works but in windows 10 you have to run the command from diskpart.exe. Once I get home I will test this out and hopefully this will work.

Comment: Here's how to prevent Mac OS from mounting specific volumes. The same probably applies to all nix derivatives, using `fstab`. I've no clue how to do it on Windows, sorry. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205866/85275